# JavaCC get ParseException error when lookahead > 0

Tags: javacc, regex-lookarounds, parseexception

I'm getting this error when I try to make a simple parser. The parser should be accepting (01|10|00|11)*(00|11). When I use lookahead = 0, 00100100 will trigger an error, even though its a correct input. Because JavaCC read it as 00 1 00 1 00, not 00 10 01 00. But when I add lookahead to fix it, I got

```
Exception in thread "main" ParseException: Encountered "" at line 1, column 6.
Was expecting one of:

    at GS.generateParseException(GS.java:453)
    at GS.jj_consume_token(GS.java:337)
    at GS.q3(GS.java:50)
    at GS.q0(GS.java:17)
    at GS.q1(GS.java:32)
    at GS.q0(GS.java:14)
    at GS.q3(GS.java:43)
    at GS.q0(GS.java:17)
    at GS.main(GS.java:8)
```

Can anyone help me to find the cause? 
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
options{
    LOOKAHEAD = 4;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(GS)
public class GS {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        GS parser = new GS(System.in);
        parser.q0();
    }
}
PARSER_END(GS)

TOKEN:
{
    <END : (["\n", "\r", "\t"])+>
}


void q0():{}
{
    "1" q1() | "0" q2() | "00" q3() | "11" q3()
}

void q1():{}
{
    "0" q0()
}

void q2():{}
{
    "1" q0()
}

void q3():{}
{
    q0() | <END>
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest setting `DEBUG_PARSER` to true.

Comment: Maybe `DEBUG_TOKEN_MANGER` too.  It looks to me that it isn't finding an `END` token.  Are you sure that there is a newline, return, or tab immediately after the final digit of your input?

Comment: Apparently when given 0011, after parser read 00 and call q3(), rather than to choose q0() then read 11, on q3 it choose <END> even though there's still input left. Is there any method to force the parser to choose q0() when there's still input left?

Comment: My bad, the previous example was wrong because there's no newline, return or tab after the number and will give correct answer when given 0011"/n". 
But even though I've add newline or return, it still have the same problem when given a longer string.

Comment: I'd suggest deleting the question or rewriting it to include an actual example input on which your parser fails.  As it stands, the question provides no evidence that there is a problem to solve or a question to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that writing

```
void q3():{}
{
    <END> |q0()
}
```

instead of

```
void q3():{}
{
    q0() | <END>
}
```

may fix the problem : if you inline q3, you can see that q0 is left recursive, so you need an infinite look-ahead to choose the alternative production. Putting END first will give it a higher priority, and the production will become right recursive.